# BDLC needs Excel installed to read .xls files?

Tags: sharepoint, odbc, oledb, excel-2003

I am using Sharepoint 2007 and Business Data List Connector web part to try to transform some Excel 2003 files into Sharepoint lists. On a virtual machine running Windows Server 2003 and with Microsoft Office 2003 installed I managed to do this. When trying to do the same thing on a server with Windows Server 2003 but with no Microsoft Office installed, but when I try to run the query the error I am getting is:
  ***ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] 'Project$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.** *,
 the query being

```
select * from [Project$]
```

I tried to connect to the Excel file using OleDB and ODBC and when I validate the connection the message that I receive in both cases is
 ***Connected to: C:\TEST-EXCEL (System.Data.Odbc). Connection server version: 08.00.0000 ***

Do I also need Microsoft Office installed on the Server or the problem is from somwhere else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why, when I moved the file to the server, the name of the Project sheet changed to the original name, a longer one. After changing the name in the query to the original sheet name it's working fine.